# show first 5 lines after match pattern found in vi editor

Tags: linux, search, vi

I would like to see  `first 5 lines  after the match found` in vi editor. What is the command?

I only know these commands

**`/Incident Id:`**   *Gives all lines from first to last*

**`:g/Incident ID:`**  gives only the match word hiding all non match

But how to show   first 5 lines after the match word found... ?

---

**Example** with expected output :

i have text of 8 lines, & i search for **Incident ID**

```
    Incident ID: 1392875740716  <<<Match word here
    URL: /Project/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1092)
            at com.cando.restaurant.utils.DateRange.createForWeek(DateRange.java:54)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor :110)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation 
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor
```

**Expected output**

```
  Incident ID: 1392875740716  <<<Match word here
    URL: /Project/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1092)
            at com.cando.restaurant.utils.DateRange.createForWeek(DateRange.java:54)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "only first 5 lines after the match found" as vi will display an entire file.

If you want to only see this output you could use grep instead of vi

```
$ grep -A 5 'Incident Id:' <your input file>
```

Comment: i tried but it simply moved to next line without showing any output. Did you see the example which i shown you in my question?

Comment: Thank you now i got it. But it will be very helpfull i can do the same in vi editor too

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
:g/Incident ID/#5
```

Also see `:help :g`, `:help :p` and `:help :z` (that's if you have `vim`, not `vi`).

Comment: Is it possible in vim to specify a negative number this way to achieve a line-block from that earlier line up to the /regex/ line?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not specifically a vim command but you can try it on any file from vim editor. Vim also allows you to execute a command directly from the editor, without needing to drop to a shell, by using bang (!) followed by the command to be run. So:

`:!grep  -A 5 "Incident ID" filename.txt`

from grep man pages :

> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>                 Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of
>   matches.
>
> -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>                 Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of
>   matches.

Comment: I think you used wrong command there. First in normal mode press `:` to enter command mode and then type this command  `!grep -A 5 "Incident ID" filename.txt`